# KeyError while CreateView with two ForeignKey relationships

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, keyword-argument

### Models

I have created two models within the Journals app. One model is for journal (`to_journal`) and the other one is for Journal entries (`to_journal_entry`). to_journal model is related to user model via "journal user" and to_journal_entry model is related to to `to_journal` via the `journal_name`.

It looks something like this:

[image]

**models.py**

```
class to_journal(models.Model):
    journal_name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='journal_name')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    journal_user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.journal_user) + " " + self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('to-journals')


class to_journal_entry(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    journal_name = models.ForeignKey(to_journal, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    journal_user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.journal_name) + " " + str(self.entry_date)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('to_journals', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

### Views

I have successfully set up the CreateView for the `to_journal`. On the relevant page I enter the journal name I want give my journal, press the "Add" button and the page updates, displaying the updated list of journals. This is achieve with the `CreateToJournal` view below.

[image]

I want to achieve the same thing for journal entries. Once I am "inside" any given journal, I want to be able to enter the text and I want the page to reload and update the list of entries for that specific journal only.

[image]

### Error

Once I press the add button here, this is the error I get:

[image]

For this line:

[image]

I have ran into issues on this step. When I am writing my `form_valid`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        current_journal_id = to_journal.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
        form.instance.journal_user = self.request.user
        form.instance.journal_name = current_journal_id.journal_name
        return super(ToJournalEntriesList, self).form_valid(form)
```

I specify the user by saying `form.instance.journal_user = self.request.user` and the current journal by saying `form.instance.journal_name = to_journal.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id']).journal_name` or something similar (below is the list of other things I have tried).

**views.py**

```
class CreateToJournal(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = to_journal
    template_name = 'to_journals/to_journal_list.html'
    fields = ('journal_name',)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.journal_user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateToJournal, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateToJournal, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['to_journals'] = to_journal.objects.filter(journal_user=self.request.user)
        return context


class ToJournalEntriesList(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = to_journal_entry
    template_name = 'to_journals/to_journal_entries_list.html'
    fields = ('body',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('to-journal-entries')

def form_valid(self, form):
    # line below should get the current object (Parent Journal)
    current_journal_id = to_journal.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])

    form.instance.journal_user = self.request.user

    # Line below should set the journal name for the form as the journal name of the object I got earlier.
    form.instance.journal_name = current_journal_id.journal_name
    return super(ToJournalEntriesList, self).form_valid(form)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ToJournalEntriesList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['to_journal_entries'] = to_journal.objects.filter(journal_user=self.request.user)
    context['to_journal_entries'] = to_journal_entry.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    return context
```

**I have tried**

- form.instance.journal_name = to_journal.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('id'))
- form.instance.journal_name = to_journal.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
- get_object_or_404(to_journal, id=self.kwargs.get('id'))
- get_object_or_404(to_journal, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
- form.instance.journal_name = to_journal.objects.get(journal_name=self.kwargs.get('journal_name'))

These give me the `DoesNotExist` error, which is weird, since I am located in the journal it should automatically pickup.

### Database

Just wanted to also show the database I am working with. It has an `id` column, so hypothetically should be working fine:

[image]

### Template

```
<h1 class="green-button" onclick="inputJournal(); this.onclick=null;">Add Entry</h1>
  <div id="new-journal">
     <form class="" id="myForm" action="" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form }}
       <button type="submit" id="add-button">Add</button>
     </form>
  </div>
```

Sorry for the long post! If there is any extra information needed I will be happy to provide more. I really appreciate you all taking a look.

Best,
Rasul

## Edit

### URLs

**to_journals/urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import CreateToJournal, ToJournalEntriesList


urlpatterns = [
    path('', CreateToJournal.as_view(), name='to-journals'),
    path('<slug:slug>', ToJournalEntriesList.as_view(), name='to-journal-entries'),
]
```

**root urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    path('', include('pages.urls')),

    path('to-journals/', include('to_journals.urls')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

## Edit 2

After the suggested answer, this is the new error.

[image]

[image]

## Edit 3 - working fix (Thanks Daniel Roseman)

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
        current_journal = to_journal.objects.get(journal_user=self.request.user, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.journal_user = self.request.user
        form.instance.journal_name = current_journal
        return super(ToJournalEntriesList, self).form_valid(form)
```

The change is in the the kwargs call (slug instead of id) and in the naming convention `current_journal` instead of `current_journal_id`

Comment: But do you actually have the journal id in the kwargs? Show your URLs.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman

I am happy you commented, because I am actually not entirely sure what you are referring to. 

Additionally, I would have to come forward, I am not that familiar with the concept of args and kwargs (although I do know it has something to do with dictionaries). Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.kwargs` contains the named parameters that were passed in the URL for that view. As we can see from the patterns, the only kwarg that is passed in the URL is `slug`, which clearly references the slug field of the journal; in the case of the screenshot, `sleep`. So that's what we need to use in the method, both for the value and the field to look it up against:

```
current_journal_id = to_journal.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

But please give your objects names reflecting what they actually are. Above we get the actual journal, not the id; call it `current_journal`. Similarly, the foreign key from the entry points to to the journal, not the journal name; you should name the FK `to_journal` (although I also don't understand why your model is called that in the first place, rather than just `Journal`).

**Edit**

Your second problem is directly caused by your confusing naming convention. It should be:

```
form.instance.journal_name = current_journal_id
```

(not `current_journal_id.journal_name`). If you'd named things properly, it would be

```
form.instance.journal = current_journal
```

which would be much clearer and less prone to error.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I wish this would have worked, but now the issue is that the get function return MultipleObject (since two different users had journal called Airport). Then if I add the journal_user=self.request.user argument, it "works" but the next error that is thrown at me is the 
```ValueError at /to-journals/airports
Cannot assign "'Airports'": "to_journal_entry.journal_name" must be a "to_journal" instance.
```

This is driving me nuts. Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: btw, the model is called to_journal is because in the beginning they were supposed to be "Thoughts On Journals", now the concept is slightly changed, but it is a drag to change everywhere.

Comment: Well, slugs must be unique, there's no two ways about it. If you somehow have duplicates, you should delete them.

Comment: I've made renaming as per your suggestion and now the POST request is submitted successfully. Do you have any advice or resource about naming conventions for me to improve on going forward. Thanks for your help you are the coolest! (I know have a different issue, but I will google that first) Is there any place online where I could learn more about you? I am a big fan of yours. Thanks